# How I Can Receive Element Value Of Another Site With Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, imdb

Example : How I Received "duration" id value on "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0145487/" (its not really exists!)

If you know better way to received IMDB Info with JavaScript please tell me :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMDb [forbids scraping](http://www.imdb.com/conditions). Try the [OMDb API](https://www.omdbapi.com/).

Comment: That's Really Perfect  That's All OF I Want :) Thank You ❤️